# Use Consul to store environment variables for kubernetes containers

Tags: kubernetes, consul, configmap

I would like to use consul (or would you recommend another technology?) to store environment variables that are used in a kubernetes pod/container. I have a software which uses those environment variables to setup its application state.

I heard that I could use consul for that, but I have to use something like consul because of business reasons and the pipeline for setting and distributing that configuration to other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try in [envconsul](https://github.com/hashicorp/envconsul)

Install it in your pods to transform configs from consul to enviroment variables

Comment: Thanks wagner. It was the solution that I ended up with, I added it to the container and then inside the container, wrapped up php-fpm with envconsul. It works great and even has a live configuration so any changes in consul are instantly mirrored into the code!